# Scala List indexOf has bug?

Tags: scala, list, indexof

I am reading scala API of List, I found out: indexOf(elem: A, from: Int)

so I run following code:

```
scala> List(1,3,5,8).indexOf(8,-2)
res393: Int = 1

scala> List(1,3,5,8).indexOf(8,-3)
res391: Int = 0
```

why is this result?
My Scala version is 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).

Comment: Doc link:http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#indexOf(elem:A,from:Int):Int

Comment: It seems that behaviour for negative values of `from` parameter is undefined. If you try to run it for `Vector` like `Vector(1,3,5,8).indexOf(8,-2)` it will return `3`.

Comment: I think it _is_ a bug, and it should be reported! In Spark 2.12.1 a similar bug was fixed for Vectors and other `SeqLike` implementations (see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9936) - but only `SeqLike` was fixed, while `LineraSeqOptimized` was not - see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* a bug (although indeed there's no clear documentation of the expected results when `from` is negative) - and **thanks to your question**, it will be fixed in 2.12.2: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5621

So - good catch!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior isn't a bug, simply undefined (although quite surprising, and inconsistent depending on the collection you're using).

---

On `List`, `.indexOf` will end up calling [`.indexWhere`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L116) (on `LinearSeqOptimized`), where a negative number will end up shifting the result:

```
override /*SeqLike*/
def indexWhere(p: A => Boolean, from: Int): Int = {
  var i = from                 // -3
  var these = this drop from   // no effect
  while (these.nonEmpty) {
    if (p(these.head))
      return i                 // may return a negative number

    i += 1
    these = these.tail
  }
  -1
}
```

---

As noted by @adamwy in the comments, calling `.indexOf` with a negative number on a `Vector` will not have the same result; it will call [`.indexWhere`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L202) (on `IndexedSeqOptimized`):

```
override /*SeqLike*/
def indexWhere(p: A => Boolean, from: Int): Int = {
  val start = from max 0        // completely ignores negatives 'from' input
  negLength(start + segmentLength(!p(_), start))
}
```

Comment: Not that it would make a difference and you are right, but isn't `List`'s `indexWhere` defined in `LinearSeqOptimized`?